# What are "derivatives of $f$ at point $a \in \text{domain}$"?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The 1994 paper "Higher Order Derivatives and Differential Cryptanalysis" uses the following unfamiliar (to me) syntax in a definition:

> Let $(S,+)$ and $(T,+)$ be Abelian groups. For a function $f : S \to T$, the *derivatives of $f$ at point $a \in S$* is defined as
>   $$\Delta_af(x) = f(x+a) - f(x)$$

I don't understand this syntax, or how this could be true.  Consider the function $f(x) = x + 9$.  The derivative of this (expressed either as $\frac{d}{dx}$ or $f'(x)$) is 1.  Yet according to the definition given, it should be

$$\Delta_2f(x) = f(x+2) - f(x) = 2$$

My questions are as follows.

- Does the syntax used indicate some different meaning of the term "derivative"?  If so, what does "derivative" mean here?
- What does it mean to take a "derivative of $f$ at point $a \in S$"?  Ordinarily I would assume that this meant to take the derivative, then substitute $x=a$ and solve, but that doesn't appear to be what is meant here.

Comment: Maybe it is assumed above that the groups have a *discrete* topology?

Comment: I'm not sure what you think you don't understand about the syntax.  You seem to have interpreted it just fine in your example.

Comment: Thanks @EricWofsey, that makes sense now! I really wish the authors wouldn't use a very well-defined term and redefine it to mean something else, but I guess I can't do anything about that. Makes it much more difficult to read this paper...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement is a *definition*, not an assertion.  That is, the equation $$\Delta_af(x) = f(x+a) - f(x)$$ is a definition of the term "derivatives of $f$ at $a$" in this context.  It is related to other definitions of derivative you may have seen in other contexts, but you shouldn't worry about whether it's exactly the same, because it's not meant to be the same.

As for the phrasing "at $a$", I agree that that phrasing is a bit odd, but again, it's just a definition.  It is probably more appropriate to think of $\Delta_a f(x)$ as a "directional derivative of $f$ in the $a$ direction at $x$", if you want to get intuition from calculus.